# Cycles: Ambient Light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have disabled all lights, why can I see the textures? There is some ambient light going on, how can I disable all of it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [*Ambient Occlusion*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/world_settings.html) enabled in the *World* tab. Uncheck it and your scene will be dark.

[image]